# if string is alphabetically greater than other string in objective

Tags: objective-c, string, alphabetical

I'm trying to use an if statement to work out which of 2 strings comes first alphabetically. Like with numbers and greater and less than:

```
if (1 < 2) {
```

just with strings:

```
if(@"ahello" < @"bhello") {
```

Or would I have to have a string containing all the letters and then check the index of the first char in each string and see which index is greater, and the index that is less than the other comes first in the alphabet and then if they are equal move on to the next char and repeat?

Comment: just as in C your if statement is comparing the pointers to the strings and not the content of the strings.

Comment: that was just an example of what I meant

Answer (score 39, accepted):

What you can do is:

```
NSString *stringOne = @"abcdef";
NSString *stringTwo = @"defabc";

NSComparisonResult result = [stringOne compare:stringTwo];

if (result == NSOrderedAscending) // stringOne < stringTwo
    ...

if (result == NSOrderedDescending) // stringOne > stringTwo
    ...

if (result == NSOrderedSame) // stringOne == stringTwo
    ...
```

There are also other methods for performing different kinds of comparisons (such as case-insensitivity, diacritic insensitivity, etc), but the result of the comparison can still be treated like the above. Alternatively, some people find it easier to compare `result` to 0. The operator used to compare `result` to 0 would be the same operator used in other languages where string comparisons can be done directly:

```
if (result < 0) // stringOne < stringTwo
    ...

if (result > 0) // stringOne > stringTwo
    ...

if (result == 0) // stringOne == stringTwo
    ...
```

Most (if not all) of the `compare:...` methods of NSString are wrappers for [`compare:options:range:locale:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/compare:options:range:locale:). The different kinds of options that you can pass can be found [here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-DontLinkElementID_184).

Answer (score 4):

NSString has a whole slew of `compare:` methods to do just what you want.  Some are very simple, and others have a bunch of options you can use to customise the behaviour.  Check out the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html).